# Extension methods for EF Core 6 using Linq for repo pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to create a repository style pattern for EF Core 6. I know most folks say I don't need to, but I'd like to have functions like.

For example it makes the code look neater.

```
GetALL();
GetSingleRecord(1); 
Update(record);
```

I was trying something like this in EF Core 6:

```
public static class ConciergeExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Rooms> GetAllRooms(this DbSet<Rooms> rooms)
    {
        return rooms;
    }

    public static Rooms GetSingleRoom(this DbSet<Rooms> rooms, int Id)
    {
        return rooms.Where(w => w.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

But when I go to access my method, it cannot be found:

```
 public Rooms GetSingleRoom() => db.Rooms.GetSingleRoom()
```

Comment: I don't think you can. It's a static class against a scoped dbcontext

Comment: I am using extension methods on DbSet<T> currently. They are static methods as they must be.

Comment: This is not related to the repository pattern and you better state the question differently because it needlessly sparks an old debate. All you have here is a couple of extension methods. And I don't think they're useful. What's neater about `context.Rooms.GetAllRooms()` vs the regular `context.Rooms`, or `context.Rooms.GetSingleRoom(1)` vs the common alternative `context.Rooms.Find(1)`?

Comment: @csharpdudeni77 if your problem solved as described can you mark as answer ?

Comment: Please do not hound someone for a marked as answer your solution may have not been correct its not the stackoverflow way !

Comment: At least the answer tells you that `db.Rooms.GetSingleRoom()` doesn't pass an `Id`. In fact, it's a different method than your extension method.

Answer (score -1):

Because you didn't pass parameter `id` or `roomId` into extension method that querying in `where` condition,

```
  public Rooms GetSingleRoom(int roomId) => db.Rooms.GetSingleRoom(roomId)
```

Here is my already working example extension method.

```cs
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyFilter<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter) where TEntity : class
    {
      return query.AsQueryable().Where(filter);
    }
    ...

    // SomeService.cs
    
    using DAL.EntityExtensions; // --> Implementation here

    public User Get(Expression<Func<Admin, bool>> filter = null)
    {
       return _context.User.ApplyFilter(filter).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Try this, hope it helps

Comment: it still says cannot navigate to it when i check goto defination

Comment: Did you implement `using namespace_of_extension.ConciergeExtensions;`? On windows `ctrl + (left) click` on method to goto definition.